# State design pattern for game objects in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Trying to implement a state design pattern for game objects. Considering the fact that each state is accompanied by a visual change of the client object that may involve animations, this quickly raises the problem: Do the states have access to visual properties of the context object or do they simply ask the context object for visual change (which would be a bit limited)?

An example: Say I have a door that has multiple states: open, closed, locked, sealed... This would mean having a Door object along with an abstract DoorState class and concrete classes DoorOpenState, DoorClosedState, DoorLockedState and DoorSealedState. Knowing that the door appearance changes with each state, should for example the DoorOpenState have access to the internal visual properties of the Door? How can it do that without having to expose private information to the outside? In C++, defining states as friend classes would probably solve the problem but how would one approach such a problem in Objective C or any modern language like C# or Java?

Thanks

Comment: I'd personally create something that knows how to render objects based on their state... so the Door object maintains it's state, that's it.. then another object DoorRenderClient or something see when the door state changes and knows how to change your rendering to match

Comment: something along the lines of how FB's react.js handles things I imagine...

Comment: Does that mean that the Door class would have a DoorRenderer that takes in a DoorState and knows how to render it?

Comment: What I was saying is: call Door.SetState(newState). DoorRenderer sees Door.state changed, then updates the scene appropriately.

Comment: Why did you make DoorState an object? If it's just opened/closed/locked/sealed, couldn't you use integer constants?